# jQuery Cycle, Transition effect not working when I add a timeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Please see [this reference URL](http://www.graphictankclients.co.uk/veredor/) to get a better idea of what I mean.

I'm having trouble with the jQuery Cycle plugin in the when I add a timeout to auto transition the slide the transition effect (in this case a fade) stops working.

These are the options I'm using.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  'normal', 
timeout: 5000, 
});
```

If anyone could give me any ideas that would be a great help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The last comma makes the code invalid.

Use:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  'normal', 
timeout: 5000
});
```